# Advice on carrying a video tripod on a bicycle, please

Tags: panniers

I wonder whether there is anyone who carries a video tripod (Manfrotto 525 - 75mm bowl head) on their bike, rather than a dslr tripod. The thing is that although I use a DSLR camera for my filming, I am often using long lenses and accessories such as monitors, lens hood, lights, etc and I need a sturdier tripod. DSLR tripods just don't cut it for the kind of work I do.

I like the mobility of a bike as I can be anywhere so quickly, but I would like to be able to carry a video tripod. I have seen some people using a pannier rack but I wonder whether a video tripod would be too much?

Any advice would be immensely appreciated.

[image]
[image]

Regards

Sam

Comment: Information about how big and heavy the thing is would be much more useful than the (used without copyright, as usual) photos.

Comment: In as much as the overall page constitutes a critical review of the product's fitness for a purpose, a public promotional image from the manufacturer is defensible fair use pretty much everywhere.  (although probably should be attributed since I imagine by posting it to SE without any the asker would be implying they have the right to relicense it CDDL?)

Comment: I see no reason why you couldn't strap this atop a rear rack.  The main concern would be leg clearance as you mounted the bike, if you typically that by swinging your leg over the rear.  Modern tripod weight is typically under 10 pounds, so weight should not be a problem.

Comment: Well, not really. That post/ question is about a DSLR tripod, which can be very small and compact and some of them are so compact you can even attach it to the front wheel frame. A video tripod is a lot bigger is every sense. The tripod legs specs (without the head) are, Closed length: 28.35 in.; color: black; head bowl: 75mm.; leg cross-section: round.; 3 leg sections; leg tube diameter: 16. 25mm; load capacity: 33.07 lbs.; material: aluminum; maximum height: 61.42 in.; minimum height: 14.17 in.

Comment: I am accepting that i will have the remove the head and travel with it unmounted to reduce space. `I wonder still if it too large, even without the head

Answer (score 2):

Racks have load ratings, and high-quality racks may be rated for 30–40 kg loads. Your tripod should be well within those limits.

How you attach it is another story, and you may need to get creative. A longtail cargo bike might be a better bet if you're routinely hauling long lenses and tripods.

Comment: The common values I've seen for rack ratings are 9 kg/20 lb for a beam-style rack and either 22 kg/50 lb, or 25 kilos for a rack that is braced off the rear.  Another issue is the fragility of cameras and lenses and lights etc.  The tripod is comparably robust.

Comment: Tubus and Blackburn both make heavy duty racks (40kg IIRC)

Comment: A one-wheeled cargo trailer may be better suited than a rack.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am checking them out now.